# About the mac weka connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, macos, weka

[image: error]

I have added `java-connect-5.1.41.jar` to the directory `weka-oracle-jvm/content/java`, but when I open DB and connect, it returns false and I get the error:

> Unable to find a suitable driver to jdbc.

I have change the `./bash_profile`:

`export CLASSPATH = ".../weka.jar:/.../java-connect-5.1.41.jar"`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have downloaded the right file. If you're using MySQL, the file that you have to copy should be of the format "mysql-connector-java-version-bin.jar". The download link is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

I have also posted a full work-around [here](https://redd.it/82sjlz). Do let me know if it works for you.